# How do you check if an image is present whilst using a multiple conditional IF statement in c# using resources

Tags: c#, image, if-statement, resources, compare

I am trying to use a simple IF statement to check if text is present AND if a pictures is also present.   But it will not recognise the picture.

I am checking if the picture is present in an array of buttons.

I can not get the message box to appear.

I have deleted the part that say " && buttonArray[i].Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.flag "

and that part of the code runs.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
            if (buttonArray[i].Text == "B" && buttonArray[i].Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.flag)

            {

                MessageBox.Show("You Win!");
            }
        }
```